# How do I create a static member variable of an object that has static variables itself?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a robust way to write a class that has a `static` member variable when that object itself has `static` variables of its own?

In the example provided below, where `Bar` has a static variable of type `Foo`, and `Foo` has a static variable of type `string`, I am getting a segfault when `bar.cpp` is compiled before `foo.cpp`.

How can I structure this so that it works no matter the order in which the files are provided?

`foo.h`

```cpp
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
  static const std::string STATIC_FOO;
  Foo(): m_foo(STATIC_FOO) {};
  std::string m_foo;
};

#endif
```

`foo.cpp`

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "foo.h"
const std::string Foo::STATIC_FOO = "foo";
```

`bar.h`

```cpp
#ifndef BAR
#define BAR
#include "foo.h"

class Bar {
public:
  static Foo s_foo;
};

#endif
```

`bar.cpp`

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
Foo Bar::s_foo;
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "bar.h"

int main() {
  Bar b;
  std::cout << b.s_foo.m_foo << std::endl;
}
```

This compiles fine when I specify `foo.cpp` before `bar.cpp`:

```bash
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp -o main
$ ./main
Foo!
```

But if `bar.cpp` is compiled first, I get a segmentation fault:

```bash
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp bar.cpp foo.cpp -o main  # note bar.cpp comes before foo.cpp here
$ ./main
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Use a proper [_Singleton_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) instead. What you're experiencing is the [**Static Initialization Order Fiasco**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)

Comment: The problem is called [Static Initialisation Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof). C++ imposes no order in which translation units are compiled, which means you cannot rely that one global object in one file exists when creating another in a different file. Using Meyer's singleton instead of global/static objects is a good workaround to avoid this issue (or, better yet, try to avoid global objects altogether)

Comment: Terminology note: Both compile "fine". Logic errors are outside the compiler's area of concern.